# How to call a methods to a button?

Tags: c#, methods

i want to implement the following method whose function is to clear text boxes but am facing a problem in calling it on the button.I want that when the button is pressed all textboxes should be cleared. The following is my code:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)  
{  
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)  
    {  
        if (c is TextBox)  
        {  
            ((TextBox)c).Clear();   
        }   

    } 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean having a problem `calling it on the button` are you wanting to do something with a button as well in this code...? please edit your question and make yourself more clearer..

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this if you are familiar with lambda

```
Your_Form_Name.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method from your Button Click() handler and pass the Form in:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ClearTextBoxes(this);
    }

    private void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Clear();
            }
            else if (c.HasChildren)
            {
                ClearTextBoxes(c);
            }
        }
    }
```